# Check if email is hosted by gmail in PHP

Tags: php, gmail

I need to check if given email if hosted by google.com or googlemail.com
Right now I check if it ends on @gmail.com or @googlemail.com, but this method doesn't work for all the emails, since google provides it's functionality for external services, and their emails can end on something like @abc.edu

How can I run a DNS query on the MX record to find that email is hosted by google?

Comment: This is off topic please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The topics I can ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dns_get_record()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)

```
function is_google_mx($host) {
    $records = dns_get_record($host, DNS_MX);
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        if (substr(strtolower($record['target']), -11) == '.google.com') return true;
        if (substr(strtolower($record['target']), -15) == '.googlemail.com') return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: works, thank you, I see my mistake now